XGBoost: specify last variable in every node
I am modeling the probability of breast cancer (not using the dataset in the example below, I can't upload my own), and I have a treatment variable that I consider my most important variable. If the patient responds to the treatment, this variable needs to be monotonically increasing (nothing else makes sense). There are some patients that respond to the treatment, and some do not respond. I want to build a complex tree model where the leaf node (last node) is always the treatment variable (if this branch of the tree responds to the treatment - thus increasing the predictive power of my model).
When defining an xgboost model (for logistic regression), is it possible to specify that I want a specific variable (my treatment variable) to come at the leaf node, if it improves the predictive quality of the model?
My attempt thus far (in the code below worst symmetry is a proxy for my treatment variable)?
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
# read data
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = load_breast_cancer()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['data'], data['target'], test_size=.2)
# create model instance
params = {"n_estimators":5, "max_depth":5, "learning_rate":1}
params_constrained = params.copy()
params_constrained['monotone_constraints'] = {"worst symmetry": 1}
#bst = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=5, max_depth=5, learning_rate=1, objective='binary:logistic')
bst = XGBRegressor(objective='binary:logistic', kwargs=params_constrained)
# fit model
bst.fit(X_train, y_train)
# make predictions
preds = bst.predict(X_test)

But, how to add the restriction on 'worst symmetry' variable, that I want it to come at the leaf node (if at all?)? Can I use interaction_constraints possibly?

Problem is that xgboost is not a tree based model in common sence, it is a boosting model. This means that result is a sum of many trees result=sum(tree_i). Usually first tree have the largest impact on the result and the last tree don't improve final result by a lot. Thus if you ask to ammend a leaf split in which tree do you want to create this leaf? In the first tree or in the last tree? Or in all trees? Basically this task simply doesn't make sense. I would propose to use SHAP values to estimate impact of your feature instead of editing the boosting procedure.
